# Add 'Activity Filter' Option

Tags: contacts, activities

I want to add a Activity Filter Option that filters the activity down to the "Assigned To".

in the ActivityFilter.php i have added this line of code:

```
    $assigneeDefault = CRM_Core_Session::getLoggedInContactID();
    $this->add('text', 'assignee_contact_id', ts('Task Owner'), $assigneeDefault, FALSE, ['class' => 'crm-form-text']);
```

Then in the selector.tpl i added this:

```
   <td class="crm-contact-form-block-activity_assignee_contact_id crm-inline-edit-field">
       <label>{ts}Task Owner{/ts}</label><br /> {$form.assignee_contact_id.html|crmAddClass:medium}
   </td>
```

Unfortunately no luck to confirm:

I want a filter that shows only the activities 'Assigned To' a certain contact.

Thanks,

Moe

Comment: Do I assume correctly you have edited the core files with your change? You should not do that, you should write an extension to customize CiviCRM behaviour (check https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/). Or is this in an extension?

Comment: @ErikH-CiviCooP - I have actually created an extension not editing the core files but to make it easier i make it seem like i edited the core files? Any ideas on how to do this? I am not knowing the best way round it?

Comment: @petednz - fuzion -  If memory serves, this should be doable with the Views module in Drupal, right? Moe, I agree that filtering by Assigned [to] should be in the Civi UI anyway.